# Javascript overlay whilst everything loads in background

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

So i'm a little new to rails and javascript,

I love the look of this, http://codepen.io/msisto/pen/LntJe

Heres the codepen code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-forever {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate-forever {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate-forever {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.loading-spinner {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate-forever;
  -moz-animation-name: rotate-forever;
  animation-name: rotate-forever;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 8px solid #ffffff;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
  background: #774CFF;
}

.loading-spinner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -15px 0 -15px;
}

<body>
  <div class="loading-spinner"></div>
</body>
```

However i'm not sure how i can get this into my application. I'm wanting to have it so that this spins before each page loads.

Any ideas what i can do? any gems for this or?

Comment: Just a side note (and to be a bit picky), `keyframes` and `transform` are CSS(3) properties. Nothing to do with Javascript. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4+ comes with [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) gem.

You use this [events](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events) to show/hide the loading before page loads.

Comment: Hey, Sorry passed out last night, How would i go about putting this into my application? i really do like the spinner however!